# Does PhoneGap go hand-in-hand with ASP.Net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, .net, cordova, webforms

I'm new to PhoneGap and everywhere I looked doesn't suggest anything about using webforms as server code.

> The application server is normally a web server (Apache, IIS, etc...) and has a server side scripting language such as ColdFusion, Java, .NET, PHP, etc... PhoneGap is agnostic of back-end technologies and can work with any application server using standard web protocols.   The application server performs business logic and calculations, and generally retrieves or persists data from a separate data repository - this is normally a relational database, but could be any structure or mechanism for data persistence.

http://phonegap.com/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/

This article however, mentioned that PhoneGap is able to work with just about any application server including .Net.

Has anyone used PhoneGap with webform before? Do they work?
What about the form postbacks etc? Or everything should be AJAX-based? (Calling webmethods etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the end of the linked article:

> PhoneGap applications generally do not talk directly to a database;
>   communication is routed through an application server.    The client
>   to application server communication can be based upon standard HTTP
>   requests for HTML content, REST-ful XML services, JSON services, or
>   SOAP (or websockets if your OS supports it).  These are the exact same
>   techniques that you would use in a desktop-browser based AJAX)
>   application.
>
> The client-side architecture generally uses the single-page
>   application model, where the application logic is inside a single HTML
>   page.  This page is never unloaded from memory.  All data will be
>   displayed by updating the HTML DOM, data is retrieved from the
>   application server using AJAX techniques, and variables are kept
>   in-memory within JavaScript.

So yes, in general you wouldn't use postbacks, you would use Ajax calls back to the server in order to get/create/update data - which is supported by asp.net webforms via handlers (ashx) or even static page methods on an aspx page. Your actual front-end you just design in HTML and CSS, no asp.net controls, just plain old html inputs, etc.

Comment: That's what I think too. Single page design and JSON services. Thanks for your answer!